# ChartJS: create linear x-axis on bar chart

Tags: chart.js

I'm plotting the following data on a webpage using ChartJS:

```
SeriesData = [
  { x: 1.0, y: 2 },
  { x: 1.1, y: 8 },
  { x: 1.2, y: 12 },
  { x: 1.3, y: 3 },
  { x: 1.4, y: 5 },
  { x: 1.5, y: 2 },
  { x: 1.6, y: 11 },
  { x: 1.7, y: 18 },
  { x: 1.8, y: 9 },
  { x: 1.9, y: 10 },
  { x: 2.0, y: 12 },
  { x: 2.1, y: 9 },
  { x: 2.2, y: 12 },
  { x: 2.3, y: 14 },
  { x: 2.4, y: 5 },
  { x: 2.5, y: 12 },
  { x: 2.6, y: 10 },
  { x: 2.7, y: 11 },
  { x: 2.8, y: 16 },
  { x: 2.9, y: 10 },
  { x: 3.0, y: 2 }
];
```

I'm trying to create a linear x-axis that only lists out whole integers. This is what I have so far:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: SeriesData.map(i => i.x),
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Series Data',
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
        data: SeriesData.map(i => i.y)
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            type: 'linear',
            min: 0,
            max: 3,
            stepSize: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      yAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            min: 0,
            max: 20
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

However, I'm getting the following chart:

[image: chartjs image]

Is there anyway to show only `1...2...3` on the x-axis?

And is there any way to create a red, dashed vertical line at `x = 2.3` ? I've used the [chartjs-plugin-annotation](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation) but the line isn't showing up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve the first thing by just using below

```
labels: SeriesData.map(i => Number(i.x) === i.x && i.x % 1 === 0 ? i.x: ""),
```

This will blank it when it has a fractional value. For the 2nd part you should create jsFiddle and post the same

You can see the fiddle for this

https://jsfiddle.net/jxkc3mtd/

Answer (score 1):

To show the annotation you may use a box (because vertical line is not documented correctly)

You need to add `annoation` to your `options` property:

```
  options: {
    annotation: {
      annotations: [{
        drawTime: "beforeDatasetsDraw",
        type: 'box',
        xScaleID: 'x-axis-0',
        yScaleID: 'y-axis-0',
        xMin: 2.3,
        xMax: 2.3,
        yMin: 0,
        yMax: 20,
        backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
        borderColor: 'red'
      }]
    }
  }
```

Unfortunately this won't work, if you don't create a label for 2.3.
So you need to display the labels (which you dn't want to show, 1.1, 1.2 etc.) as white.

I have modified the example of the first answer:
https://jsfiddle.net/t1za02wr/12/